# Fix string encoding issues

Tags: c#, string, encoding

Does anyone know of a .Net library (NuGet package preferrably) that I can use to fix strings that are 'messed up' because of encoding issues?

I have Excel* files that are supplied by third parties that contain strings like:

`TelefÃ³nica UK Limited`

`ServiÃ§os de ComunicaÃ§Ãµes e MultimÃ©dia`

These entries are simply user-error (e.g. someone copy/pasted wrong or something) because elsewhere **in the same file** the same entries are correct:

`Telefónica UK Limited`

`Serviços de Comunicações e Multimédia`

So I was wondering if there is a library/package/something that takes a string and fixes "common errors" like `Ã§Ãµ` → `çõ` and `Ã³` → `ó`. I understand that this won't be 100% fool-proof and may result in some false-negatives but it would sure be nice to have some field-tested library to help me clean up my data a bit. Ideally it would 'autodetect' the issue(s) and 'autofix' them as I won't always be able to tell what the source encoding (and destination encoding) was at the time the mistake was made.

<sub>* The filetype is not very relevant, I may have text from other parties in other fileformats that have the same issue...</sub>

Comment: Nothing is going to come out the box that will do this because ultimately all data is different and what you deem a "common" mistake isn't necessarily a *general* problem. If you know what the common mistakes are in your situation why not just do a simple `String.Replace`?

Comment: I could do a "simple replace" but, as said, I was hoping for a more field-tested solution than my simple "array of fixes". I understand that all data is different but I know for PHP and Java there exist some libraries/packages (don't ask for a name, I don't know / forgot and could not find them googling before posting this question) that "autodetect" these kinds of errors and fix these (although I don't know what their "score" is e.g. if they are correct in guessing/fixing in most of the cases). I was hoping there were a .Net alternative.

Comment: The characters `Ã§` are just as valid as `ç`, how should the code know that the input shouldn't actually be `Ã§`? :)

Comment: @CodeCaster I know they are just as valid, but the specific combination of them will at least **hint** at a possible (re)encoding issue. If I could "autofix" these strings and then see if the fixed string matches other entries in the file or in my data I could be fairly certain the fix is correct. I could also use a Levenshtein on these strings and conclude they are probably the same thing but the more characters with issues in the string the bigger the Levenshtein score and thus need for a 'dynamic threshold' or something.

Comment: @RobIII it doesn't have to be an "array of fixes", you could write a generic rule-based handler (which you could use for *multiple* situations). Regardless, it seems you have your heart set on something that's already out there so I'll shut up now :)

Comment: @James `it doesn't have to be an "array of fixes", you could write a generic rule-based handler (which you could use for multiple situations)` Ofcourse, I understand, but the *essence* will be a collection of "If this problem then that fix" things. `Regardless, it seems you have your heart set on something that's already out there so I'll shut up now`: Well, for one, I just found ICU4J which I thought had some routines for "fixing" these things but, as far as I can see now in a short time, I don't think it was ICU4J and may be mistaken.

Comment: Meanwhile I found a page that contains at least some sensical, useful, pointers (for example MLang): http://www.architectshack.com/TextFileEncodingDetector.ashx. Maybe (try to) detect encoding, do a conversion, see if that makes sense (and matches other entries for example) and go from there. I'll see where I end up...

Answer (score 1):

My best advice is to start with a list of special characters that are used in the language in question.

I assume you're just dealing with Portuguese or other European languages with just a handful of non-US-ASCII characters.

I also assume you know what the bad encoding was in the first place (i.e. the code page), and it was always the same.

(If you can't assume these things, then it's a bigger problem.)

Then encode each of these characters badly, and look for the results in your source text. If any are found, you can treat it as badly encoded text.

```
var specialCharacters = "çõéó";
var goodEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var badEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
var badStrings = specialCharacters.Select(c => badEncoding.GetString(goodEncoding.GetBytes(c.ToString())));

var sourceText = "ServiÃ§os de ComunicaÃ§Ãµes e MultimÃ©dia";
if(badStrings.Any(s => sourceText.Contains(s)))
{
    sourceText = goodEncoding.GetString(badEncoding.GetBytes(sourceText));
}
```

Comment: Problem is I don't know the bad encoding; it could be anything. The files are user-edited and may have any possible "source encoding". The files could be edited by Portugese, Chinese etc. users and with that comes that each may have used their own locale / encoding etc. and who knows what they do to mess up the encoding in the first place. The bad->good conversion itself is something I'm pretty sure I'll work out. And with [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498165/fix-string-encoding-issues#comment45317151_28498165) I may just have enough pointers to detect the source enc.

Comment: ^ And by "detect" I mean "guess" ofcourse. I know (and understand) that you can never be sure as [pointed out earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498165/fix-string-encoding-issues#comment45316279_28498165). Nevertheless your input / answer is appreciated! I think I'll give [MLang](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17201/Detect-Encoding-for-In-and-Outgoing-Text) a go and see what I can come up with. I do have one advantage: the file most likely contains the correct string in several places so I should be able to guess'n'match with good probability.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in fixing a bad encoding is to find what encoding the text was mis-encoded to, often this is not obvious.

So, start with a bit of text that is mis-encoded, and the corrected version of the text. Here my badly encoded text ends with Ã¤ rather than ä

```
var name = "ViistoperÃ¤";
var target = "Viistoperä";
var encs = Encoding.GetEncodings();
foreach (var encodingType in encs)
{ 
    var raw = Encoding.GetEncoding(encodingType.CodePage).GetBytes(name);
    var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
    if (output == target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",encodingType.DisplayName, encodingType.CodePage, output);
    }
}
```

This will output a number of candidate encodings, and you can either pick the most relevant one. Windows-1252 is a better candidate than Turkish in this case.